# Getting SemanticException on a very simple query

Tags: hive, azure-hdinsight

I have the following very simple query.

```
SELECT "test" FROM mydb.mytable 
INNER JOIN yourdb.yourtable
ON    yourtable.id     = mytable.id  LIMIT 10;
```

It is failing due to the following error (indicating syntax error):-

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException MetaException(message:Exception thrown when executing query)
```

The column id is bigdata type.

Surprisingly it works if I keep the query as it is but just use a different table in place of mytable which is having exactly the same schema as mytable. Looks like Hive is not showing the meaningful error here. Anyone having clues here?

To further add to confusion check the following:-

```
-- SUCCESS – All the data up to 24th Sep 2016
SELECT "test" AS col FROM mydb.mytable INNER JOIN yourdb.yourtable ON yourtable.id = mytable.id where mytable.id <= 2016092423 LIMIT 1;

-- SUCCESS – All the data after 24Th Sep 2016
SELECT "test" AS col FROM mydb.mytable INNER JOIN yourdb.yourtable ON yourtable.id = mytable.id where mytable.id >= 2016092423 LIMIT 1;


--  ERROR – All the data up to 25th Sep 2016
SELECT "test" AS col FROM mydb.mytable INNER JOIN yourdb.yourtable ON yourtable.id = mytable.id where mytable.id <= 2016092523 LIMIT 1;
```

This is totally contradictory behavior. The first two queries cover the entire space. Considering the first two queries succeed it is totally surprising that the third query fails.

Let me depict it using a picture:-

[image]

Comment: there is nothing wrong in the schema. I added more explanation about the problem, please check. This issue is self contradictory.

Comment: "test" AS col  - is it just string constant or column named test? if it is just a constant then correct syntax is 'test' as col (single quotes)

Comment: I asked about DDL because I want to reproduce this

Comment: Have read your explanation about contradictory behavior and now I have no thoughts about how to explain this. Is it  reproducible  on small enough dataset to be posted here?

Comment: no, and also it's not possible to post data for many reasons as you can understand.

Comment: And again: please provide full exception if possible

Comment: This is all i am getting:-   FAILED: SemanticException MetaException(message:Exception thrown when executing query)

Comment: we are using HDInsight based Hadoop, which is basically Hortonworks distribution. I hope it is not a product bug either from HDInsight side or Hortonworks.